# Web-scraping in Excel with variable url (url extension)

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am fairly new to VBA and VBA in excel, I have been trying to find out how to conditionally scrape web data based off of one cells value ("Guid") and have not really found a way to progress the function -- to make it dynamic. As of right now I can only get it to retrieve data for one specific cell, and print in another specified cell.  I believe I am just missing some kind of looping variable function? (aside from there is probably a more correct way of writing the code).

```
Sub ie_open()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim TxtRng As Range
  Dim Guid As Range
  Dim ie As Object
  Dim URL As String

  URL = "https://url.com/userpage="
  Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
  Set ws = wb.Sheets("Detail Report - Individuals")
  Set Guid = ws.Range("E2")
  Set TxtRng = ws.Range("F2")
  Set ie = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.APPLICATION")

  ie.NAVIGATE (URL + Guid)
  ie.Visible = True

  While ie.ReadyState <> 4
     DoEvents
  Wend

  TxtRng = ie.document.getelementbyid("lbl_Location").innertext

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The code above is set to target only one element and one URL. What exactly was expected?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on a reference to HTML elements (Go to Tools -- References.  You should also turn on a reference to Microsoft Internet controls so you can declare IE as an InternetExplorer object rather than just an object, but it's not necessary), then you can loop through each element like

```
Sub ie_open()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim TxtRng As Range
Dim Guid As Range
Dim ie As Object
Dim URL As String
'ADDED THIS
Dim sl as Ihtmlelement
Dim r as long = 1

URL = "https://url.com/userpage="
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Detail Report - Individuals")
Set Guid = ws.Range("E2")
Set TxtRng = ws.Range("F2")
Set ie = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.APPLICATION")

ie.NAVIGATE (URL + Guid)
ie.Visible = True

While ie.ReadyState <> 4
 DoEvents
Wend

For each sl in ie.document.all
    ws.cells(r, 1).value = sl.innertext
    r = r + 1
Next

'TxtRng = ie.document.getelementbyid("lbl_Location").innertext

End Sub
```

Edit: forgot to increment the `r` variable in the loop, and I think it should be `IE.Document.All` instead of just `IE.Document` when initializing the loop